# Customizing Microsoft Office 2013 OEM Preinstallation

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2013, oem

I am trying to *preinstall* OEM Microsoft Office 2013 Professional on an *embedded Win7 image*.  This is the type of Office where the user can try it for roughly one week and then must purchase a license to continue use.

The installer won't let me configure the installation beyond language and location. In particular, I want to disable a few packages such as MS Outlook on the installation. This wouldn't be a problem if I could simply uninstall Outlook after the preinstallation - but I can't do that without uninstalling the entire Office suite.

How do I remove certain components of Office to make this preinstallation suitable for our customers?

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing with a full image of office, or the "Web install" version?  I found that the web install version prevents you from customizing the install, and rather forces you to install the whole thing.

You might try these IMG files from Microsoft's TechNet Evaluation Service.  They can be used for a full, customized install if you have your own key (such as from the Home Use Program) or they can act as 60-day evaluation versions.

[Office Professional Plus 2013, 64-bit](http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/2/9/C/29CC45EF-4CDA-4710-9FB3-1489786570A1/OfficeProfessionalPlus_x64_en-us.img?lcid=1033)

[Office Professional Plus 2013, 32-bit](http://care.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/2/9/C/29CC45EF-4CDA-4710-9FB3-1489786570A1/OfficeProfessionalPlus_x86_en-us.img?lcid=1033)

Comment: It is the "Click to Run" version.  From what I could tell, it is the full install (Office 2013) and not web-based (Office 365).

Comment: The "Click to Run" versions are web-installers.  They are not the web-based office, like 365, but they do require the internet to install.  The versions I linked are IMG files.  They are full-disc images, kind of like ISO.  You can burn to disc or open with a virtual drive like Daemon Tools or Virtual CloneDrive.